# I have a question regarding the use of Shadow DOM

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testing, frontend

In a particular scenario, I've noticed that even though a web page utilizes a Shadow DOM, I attempted to select an element using a relative XPath, and to my surprise, the element became highlighted in the browser's developer tools. I'm unsure why this element is highlighted in the context of the Shadow DOM. Can you clarify why this is happening and what might be the underlying cause of this behavior?

In the context of a web page with a Shadow DOM, I've encountered a situation where I used a relative XPath to select an element within the Shadow DOM. Surprisingly, the element is highlighted when I inspect it in the browser's developer tools. Can you explain why this element is highlighted despite being within the Shadow DOM, and what might be causing this behavior?

I would like to understand the reason why

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.